# CAN WE GIVE LAZERS A HAT

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Let's give Lazers his own custom hat.  Every robot needs to feel special...sometimes! Well, especially Lazers.  Don't neglect the poor guy.

Can we do this? Can we pull together as a community and make a hat for LAZERs? I say YES!

Comment: Lazers is a chatbot. [No chat hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159194/can-we-wear-hats-in-chat/159327#159327). Sorry~

Comment: this has to be the quickest status-declined I've ever seen!

Comment: Poor Lazers....

Comment: There is eternal dissapointment

Answer (score 6):

Lazers has a custom avatar image [chosen by badp.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3360624#3360624)  If you can generate a custom lazer-hat-avatar image and ask him real nice, he [might be willing to change it for you.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7344238#7344238)

Do note that we probably can't make an avatar image for it that exceeds the normal avatar image boundaries (like hats on the main site do)

Answer (score 5):

Lazers only exists in chat, not on the main site. Since chat doesn't have hats there's no way for us to give him a hat.