# Why can't we downvote our own questions?

Tags: support, voting

I'm just curious why we're not allowed to downvote our own questions.  I mean, if you see that your [question's topic is somewhat.....sad,](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5659/can-we-give-lazers-a-hat) then why can't you downvote it?

Comment: If you think your question is downvote worthy, the solution should be to edit your question to improve it, or flag it for close (if answers) / delete (if none). There's no reason to be able to downvote your own posts, since in the act of *posting* them, you inherently decry to have found them satisfactory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't downvote your own posts because you can't vote on your own posts.

Exceptions: voting to close, "voting" to delete.